# How can i overlay d3js directed graph on leaflet

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

I'm using leaflet.js for display world map. i want to draw directed graph with nodes that is my location and link between them as arc on leaflet map.

I look at leaflet plugin and choose [d3svgoverlay](https://github.com/teralytics/Leaflet.D3SvgOverlay) to draw graph on leaflet.

I search about directed graph with d3.js and find some example like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292).

how can i overlay above example on the leaflet?

**Note**: i don't want animate graph. i want just click on node to hide other path and i want put text on arcs and nodes.